# How do I integrate JS SDK into ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I am trying to integrate [QuickBlox chat JS sample app](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/tree/gh-pages/samples/chat) into ReactJS app.

The JS sample app has App.js file that looks like this, it uses templates using underscore.js

**App.js**

```
function App(config) {
    this._config = config;
    // Elements
    this.page = document.querySelector('#page');
    this.userListConteiner = null;
    this.init(this._config);
    this.loading = true;
}

// Before start working with JS SDK you nead to init it.

App.prototype.init = function (config) {
    // Step 1. QB SDK initialization.
    QB.init(config.credentials.appId, config.credentials.authKey, config.credentials.authSecret, config.appConfig);
};

App.prototype.loadWelcomeTpl = function () {
    
    var content = document.querySelector('.j-content'),
        welcomeTpl = helpers.fillTemplate('tpl_welcome');
    
    helpers.clearView(content);
    content.innerHTML = welcomeTpl;
};

// QBconfig was loaded from QBconfig.js file
var app = new App(QBconfig);
```

**Templates in index.html**

```
<script  type="text/template" id="tpl_welcome">
        <div class="content__title j-content__title j-welcome">
            Welcome to QuickBlox chat sample!
        </div>
        <div class="notifications j-notifications hidden"></div>
        <div class="content__inner j-content__inner">
            <div class="welcome__message">
                <p>Please select you opponent to start chatting.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

**How do I use the above in my React App**

```
const ChatApp = () => {
    
    return (
        
    );
}

export default ChatApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should get template from

```js
<script type="text/template">
...
</script>
```

and return it from your component.
Of course you should implement also business code (logic) in component code.

You can split entire sample to few small components like LoginContainer, LoginForm, Dashboard, WelcomeScreen etc...
Good start point are script templates from QuickBlox sample - each template is one React component.